# jsdifflib - How to compare text without spaces

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using [this](https://github.com/cemerick/jsdifflib/blob/master/difflib.js) library to calculate diff between two JSON objects. However, I want the comparison to be done on lines after removing extra spaces between consecutive words.

For example, `Hello    XYZ` and `Hello XYZ` should be considered the same.

I am new to Javascript and don't really know where exactly the modification will go. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `"Hello XYZ" and "Hello XYZ"` are same!!

Comment: Stackoverflow is removing extra spaces between the two words. I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Do you mean ignoring extra spaces between consecutive words which are values in the JSON object? Because I guess the lib already ignores the spaces between different properties...

Comment: No, it doesn't ignore the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple regex for removing extra spaces and then match the strings,

```js
let s = 'Hello      XYZ';
let re = /\s+/g
s = s.replace(re, ' ');
let s1 = 'Hello XYZ';
console.log(s1 === s);
```

Comment: I want that exactly but where exactly should I copy paste it in the library?

Comment: I think you should first remove extra spaces in your program then call the library for your stuff.

Comment: I cannot remove the extra spaces in the program because I want to retain the space for displaying.

Comment: Display the unremoved variables and use the variables with removed spaces for prossessing

Comment: I wish it was that easy!